# Designing a tile

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

How do I create this tile in Photoshop. I tried Bevel and Emboss as well as Inner Shadow but the result is nowhere near like this.

Comment: Note that the tile and the ? are two separate objects with separate effects. You can't do both in one step.

Comment: Bevel on the tile, Inner shadow on the question mark. Adjust settings to achieve desired effect.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, its a bevel and emboss, but then its another rounded red rectangle on top, with no effects, then its the letter with an inner shadow, to make it look like its 3d.

so its three elements
[ letter - ? - with inner shadow ]
[ smaller red rounded box, to make the top look flat]
[ red rounded box with bevel]

Also this is not an exact duplicate, but you might find some help here.
[Creating a tile for a word game](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27697/creating-a-tile-for-a-word-game)